# How to compare numbers by prime factorizations?

Tags: prime-factorization

Let's say I have two natural numbers $n$ and $m$, both of which are exceeding large, and I want to determine which is smaller. Thankfully, I happen to know both of their prime factorizations, but they're composed of many terms to high powers, so it's infeasible for me to just multiply it out and determine which is smaller that way. Hence my question is: Is there any way to compare the magnitude of two numbers, knowing only their prime factors?

As a perhaps somewhat artificial example, take:
$$n=67\times24977\times8598615939$$
$$m=2^5\times3^2\times5^5\times7^4\times13\times23^3\times421$$
Is there anyway to know $m>n$ from just those factorizarions apart from multiplying them out and comparing digits?

Comment: why you want to know that

Comment: You could multiply subsets of the factors together and hope that you could get comparisons that work, for example: $2^4 \cdot 3 > 67$

Comment: Realistically, it will take you far longer to find the prime factorization than to compare the numbers.

Comment: You could take logarithms, and compute the (faster) sums instead of the product.

Comment: @infinitylord I think the idea is that you already know the prime factorization, but not the full number.

Comment: @B.Mehta Good idea, but I think just multiplying the numbers together must be faster than computing logarithms, no ?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: I understand that, but I've never seen a problem where you know the prime factorization but not the number itself. This honestly just seems very arbitrary to me.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Potentially, but the logarithms may be more memory-efficient to store computationally and compare

Comment: agreed, it does seem like there would be no situation in which this question would have a useful answer

Comment: @TsemoAristide I'm working with primes over some various operations, and for some of those I've found ways to construct them using certain sets of the standard prime numbers. But I'm at a loss on how to go about ordering them all, or figuring out how many there are up to certain values.

Comment: @B.Mehta That would also certainly be using in dealing with all the powers, plus it shouldn't be too horrible to just make a table of logs of primes and store that... Good idea!

Comment: I think you'd have to take it on a case-by-case basis and there probably is no general algorithm that's always faster than multiplying